# How to attach TortoiseHg to already cloned repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisehg, tortoisegit

I used Git Bash cmd tool to clone a repo from bitbucket. I did it that way because some authentification issues. Now I want an interface to work with it, not the cmd tool, and i found TortoiseHg for it. But i can't find a solution to attach Tortoise to the cloned repo.

How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used git bash to clone repo, you must be talking about `git` repo, not `hg` (mercurial) repo. Note that git and mercurial are not compatible technologies.

In that case, you should use [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) (not TortoiseHg!) to access your git repo - it will work right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you use TortoiseHg,
enable the hg-git extension

```
[extensions]
hggit = C:/Program Files/TortoiseHg/hggit
```

then clone `git+https://github.com/abc/def.git` for URL.

The cloned repository will be in mercurial format, hence the hashes you see will be in mercurial format, not in git format.

Comment: I just need an interface to work with, see statuses, diff files, commit etc, I'll try TortoiseGit now